# Taking sum of "column" in MongoDB

Tags: php, math, mongodb, sum

In MySQL, I would simply go "SELECT sum(pts) FROM table" to get the sum of the pts column on the table. However, I am converting this application to MongoDB and cannot find a straightforward way to get a sum of the common key "type" in my collection. I am using PHP, so **please give PHP code to make this work.**

Here is my data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f136dab5056f65b61000000"), "p_id" : "3", "g_id" : "1", "type" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f136dad5056f65760000000"), "p_id" : "8", "g_id" : "1", "type" : "7" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f136daf5056f65860000000"), "p_id" : "6", "g_id" : "1", "type" : "4" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f136db15056f65460000000"), "p_id" : "27", "g_id" : "1", "type" : "2" }
```

How can I get $sum to equal the total of the "type" key?

Comment: Is there any reason this calculation needs to be done in the query? Why can't you just loop over the results in PHP?

Answer (score 5):

Utilizing MongoDB's new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/):

```
$result = $db->command(array(

    'aggregate' => 'COLLECTION_NAME',

    'pipeline'  => array(
        // Match:
        // We can skip this in case that we don't need to filter 
        // documents in order to perform the aggregation
        array('$match' => array(
            // Criteria to match against
        )),

        // Group:
        array('$group'  => array(
            // Groupby fields:
            '_id'       => "$fieldname1, $fieldname2, $or_empty, $etc",
            // Count:
            'count'     => array('$sum' => 1),
            // Sum:
            'type_sum'  => array('$sum' => '$type'),
        ))

        // Other aggregations may go here as it's really a PIPE :p

    ),
));
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not have a single simple query for performing a sum.

In MongoDB you will need to run a special command for this. You have three options.

1. Use [Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce). This is the general method for doing sums, counts, averages, etc across a data set. This is not trivial, you *will* need to read the documentation to understand how this works.
2. [Aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation). This is a special framework for doing "mini-Map/Reduce" jobs. The [`group` example](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) clearly demonstrates how to do "sum by type". You simply need to convert the command to PHP.
3. The [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework). This is currently only in the unstable build (2.1.0). This will be better than option #2, but it will only work on 2.1+.

> ... so please give PHP code to make this work

No simple snippet of PHP code here, aggregation is actually a complex topic in MongoDB.

First you have to pick one of the methods (#1, #2, #3) and then you have to decide what you plan to do with the output. For example, #1 Map/Reduce, can create a new collection with the aggregates or it can return the values in line, but only 10k values can be returned. Option #2 will runs in serial and will be very slow on sharded servers. Option #3 is still in "beta" and will eventually replace #2.

In any case, all of the options will require further reading before you pick a plan of attack.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the following map reduce functions:

```
var map = function () {
    emit("total", {sum:this.type}) 
    }

var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = {sum:0};
    values.forEach(function (value) {result.sum += value.type;});
    return result;
    }

db.table.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "type_totals"})
```

or in php:

```
$db->table->mapReduce( array( 
   'map' =>
   'function () {
      emit("total", {sum:this.type});
 }' 
,'reduce' =>
   'function (key, values) {
      var result = {sum:0};
      values.forEach(function (value) {result.sum += value.type;});
      return result;
     }'));
```

Comment: Are you sure about the PHP syntax? I doubt MongoCollection has a mapReduce method in PHP. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a script in the database, that will sum the require data and return your result something like:

### The Script

```
function sum() {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var query = db.collection.find({}, {type: 1, _id:0}); query.hasNext();) {
      sum += query.next();
   }
   return sum;
}
```

### PHP

In php after setting the connection with the db, it will be something like:

```
$toexec = 'function(x, y) { return sum() }';
$response = $database->execute($toexec, array());
```

Look this tutorial to learn more about scripting in mongo with php.

http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2010/08/getting-started-with-stored-procedures-in-mongodb.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$mongo = new Mongo();

$map = new MongoCode("function() { emit('total', this.type); }");
$reduce = new MongoCode("function(k, vals) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(i in vals) {
        sum += vals[i];
    }

    return sum;
}");

$sumtotal = $mongo->db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'tableName',
    'map' => $map,
    'reduce' => $reduce,
    // 'query' => array('col' => 'value'),
    'out' => array('merge' => 'tableName_sum')
));

$result = $mongo->db->selectCollection($sumtotal['result'])->findOne();
$sum = $result['value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already given lot many sources. Just giving answer for asked question:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTTION.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        total: { 
            $sum: "$type" 
        } 
    } 
} ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
$m = new MongoClient();
$con = $m->selectDB("dbName")->selectCollection("collectionName");
$cond = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => null,
           'total' => array('$sum' => '$type'),
        ),
    )
);

$out = $con->aggregate($cond);
print_r($out);
```

More detail  [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)