# Sum in nested document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to sum some values in an array of documents, with no luck.

This is the Document

db.Cuentas.find().pretty()

```
{
    "Agno": "2013",
    "Egresos": [
        {
            "Fecha": "28-01-2013",
            "Monto": 150000,
            "Detalle": "Pago Nokia Lumia a @josellop"
        },
        {
            "Fecha": "29-01-2013",
            "Monto": 4000,
            "Detalle": "Cine, Pelicula fome"
        }
    ],
    "Ingresos": [],
    "Mes": "Enero",
    "Monto": 450000,
    "Usuario": "MarioCares"
    "_id": ObjectId(....)
}
```

So, i need the sum of all the "Monto" in "Egresos" for the **"Usuario": "MarioCares"**. In this example **154000**

Using aggregation i use this:

```
db.Cuentas.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: {"Usuario": "MarioCares"} },
        { $group: 
            {
                _id: null,
                "suma": { $sum: "$Egresos.Monto" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

But i always get

```
{ "result" : [{ "_id" : null, "suma" : 0 }], "ok" : 1 }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

**P.D.** already see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162681/mongodb-2-1-aggregate-framework-sum-of-array-elements-matching-a-name) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874671/taking-sum-of-column-in-mongodb)

Comment: I believe you want to unwind the `Egresos` array first and then group on null and sum

Comment: @Sammaye added {"$unwind": $Egresos } and then i got `ReferenceError: Egresos is not defined`

Comment: You can simplify to use below code in latest versions for summing array values in a single document.`db.Cuentas.aggregate([
    {$match: {"Usuario": "MarioCares"} }, 
    {$project: { "suma": {$sum: "$Egresos.Monto" }}}
])`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Sammaye indicated, you need to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#_S_unwind) the `Egresos` array to duplicate the matched doc per array element so you can `$sum` over each element:

```js
db.Cuentas.aggregate([
    {$match: {"Usuario": "MarioCares"} }, 
    {$unwind: '$Egresos'}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: null, 
        "suma": {$sum: "$Egresos.Monto" }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do also by this way. don't need to group just project your fields.

```
db.Cuentas.aggregate([
    { $match: { "Usuario": "MarioCares" } },
    {
        $project: {
            'MontoSum': { $sum: "$Egresos.Monto" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Can you give example or snippet?

Comment: I AM SORRY @Aabid . It did not work because i was having a little different scenario in which lets say the Egresos was also a variable in the same project stage... 
But it does work in the scenario of this question..

Comment: @DagaArihant So this worked for the question you asked?

Comment: I am sorry, My case was different and i did not ask question.

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB version 3.4 you can use [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/?_ga=2.218831193.1171910152.1653217426-997394196.1631432709) to sum array items:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {Usuario: "MarioCares"}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      suma: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Egresos",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$add: ["$$value", "$$this.Monto"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCZyQ4SlahP)